# How to get collection of orders which can be shipped?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, collection, sales-order, collection-filtering

I need orders which are not shipped yet or are partially shipped. I am using below code to get orders which can be shipped.

```
foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    if ($order->canShip()) {
        echo "Shipping Pending";
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use foreach. I need something like below.

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','can_ship');
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's examine the `canShip` method to see how it is calculated:

```
/**
 * Retrieve order shipment availability
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function canShip()
{
    if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getIsVirtual() || $this->isCanceled()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_SHIP) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToShip()>0 && !$item->getIsVirtual()
            && !$item->getLockedDoShip())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The order methods can be substituted as follows

1. canUnhold()

   ```
   order->state === 'holded'
   ```
2. isPaymentReview()

   ```
   order->state === 'payment_review'
   ```
3. getIsVirtual()

   ```
   order->is_virtual === 1
   ```
4. isCanceled()

   ```
   order->state === 'canceled'
   ```
5. getActionFlag()

   Action flags are set during sales processes, not relevant for retrieving orders from the database
6. getAllItems()

   Here we need to do a join over the order items. `is_virtual` and `locked_do_ship` are columns of the `sale_flat_order_item` table.

   1. getQtyToShip()

      This again is calculated based on other attributes

      ```
      /**
       * Retrieve item qty available for ship
       *
       * @return float|integer
       */
      public function getQtyToShip()
      {
          if ($this->isDummy(true)) {
              return 0;
          }

          return $this->getSimpleQtyToShip();
      }
      ```

      `isDummy` returns is true if `parent_id === null` and the product has the "ship seperately" option OR if `parent_id !== null` and the product doesn't have the "ship seperately" option.

      `getSimpleQtyToShip` returns `qty_ordered - qty_shipped - qty_refunded - qty_canceled`.

### The code

With this information we can prepare a collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
```

First, we join the items that belong to each order:

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('order_item' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_item')),
        'main_table.entity_id=order_item.order_id', array('qty_ordered', 'qty_shipped', 'qty_refunded', 'qty_canceled', 'is_virtual', 'locked_do_ship'))
    ->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

Then, we filter order statuses that cannot be shipped ("nin" = "not in"):

```
$collection
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array(
        'holded', 'payment_review', 'canceled'
    )))
    ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_virtual', '0');
```

Then, we create an SQL expression for the number of items that can be shipped:

- we sum the shippable qty over the order items
- for virtual items the result is 0
- for "locked" items the result is 0
- for all others, the result equals `qty_ordered - qty_shipped - qty_refunded - qty_canceled`

**TODO:** take product option "ship separately into account. This query will count all parent and child items, so there will be false positives. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to also calculate the result of `isDummy()` in SQL.

The sum will be available with the alias "shippable_items"

```
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
    'shippable_items',
    'SUM(({{qty_ordered}} - {{qty_shipped}} - {{qty_refunded}} - {{qty_canceled}}) * !{{is_virtual}} * {{locked_do_ship}} IS NOT NULL)',
    array(
        'qty_ordered' => 'order_item.qty_ordered',
        'qty_shipped' => 'order_item.qty_shipped',
        'qty_refunded' => 'order_item.qty_refunded',
        'qty_canceled' => 'order_item.qty_canceled',
        'is_virtual' => 'order_item.is_virtual',
        'locked_do_ship' => 'order_item.locked_do_ship'));
```

Finally we filter only orders with a positive number of shippable items. We have to use "HAVING" instead of "WHERE" because the column is calculated with an aggregate function:

```
$collection->getSelect()->having('shippable_items > 0'));
```

Comment: good explanation .I will check.+1

Answer (score 2):

It can not possible be `because of lot  of conditions` are  check and   whenever `we use canShip()` function.Tt too complex to do that.

It is `not only depend  one /two order  fields depend` like

1. `order status hold or not.`
2. `order status cancel or not`.
3. `order virtual  or not.`
4. `Order item is capable to do ship order`

etc

So , it depends on some complex logic/condition like:

**See a view on Mage_Sales_Model_Order class**, and you can understand that.

```
 public function canShip()
    {
        if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->getIsVirtual() || $this->isCanceled()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_SHIP) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getQtyToShip()>0 && !$item->getIsVirtual()
                && !$item->getLockedDoShip())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```